# (Java) Proper use of command line execution

Tags: java, mysql, macos, terminal

I'm following a tutorial on connecting a java class to MySQL (http://zetcode.com/db/mysqljava/).  I can get the code to compile and run in Eclipse, but I'm doing something wrong when trying to run it at the command line.  I'm using OSX's terminal btw.

I perform the following to compile

```
cd dropbox/workspace/mysqltut/src/zetcode
javac Version.java
```

This successfully creates the Version.class file.

The simple version of my question is, how do I run this from the command line?  The following details my attempts using the line that the tutorial shows as well as my variations in an effort to get the class file to run properly.

If I try to run it using the tutorials command line: `java -cp .:lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar zetcode/Version.java`, I get `Error:  Could not find or load main class zetcode.Version`

So I figure, oh I'm already in zetcode so I alter it and use `java -cp .:lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar Version.java`, and this time I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Version (wrong name: zetcode/Version)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Not sure what `wrong name: zetcode/Version` means.  I'm already in zetcode.  Bear in mind I can't find what the switch `.:` means before`lib`.  I'm just going off the tutorial.  So I tried changing that switch to `../` instead since `lib` is one level up from `zetcode` (and on the same level as `src`). And I get the `Error:  Could not find or load main class Version` again.

I'm obviously jsut handling the syntax for execution incorectly since it runs fine inside the IDE.  Thnks in advance.

oh in case you need the source code, I'm using:

```
package zetcode;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Version {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Connection con = null;
        Statement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "";

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");

            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (st != null) {
                    st.close();
                }
                if (con != null) {
                    con.close();
                }

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
                lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add your current directory to your classpath. Try `:lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar;.`

Answer (score 0):

When your running from command prompt after compiling your class use this

```
java -classpath .;mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar Version
```

Keep both jar and java file in same directory and try. use ";" instead of ":"  as mentioned above.include package name if any.I have tested its working.

Comment: the .java was a typo.  I wasn't using that to begin with. I'll edit the OP.  I'm still getting the following:

Comment: Stuart Kuredjian i have edited the answer , try and let me know.

Comment: I will test now.  In the meantime can you explain what the ".:" and ".;" switches are used for? I know "../" and "/../" but i couldnt find anything on the others. Thanks.

Comment: Pravi still not working I moved `mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin` into ~/dropbox/workspace/mysqltut/src/zetcode`, which also contains `Version.class` and `Version.Java` and I ran the line `java -classpath .;mysql-connector-java-5.1.3-bin.jar Version` and received the usage list for `java [-options] class [args...]` and at the boittom it says `-bash: mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar: command not found`

Answer (score 0):

You should not compile your sources from the src directory. Compiling
should be done from the project directory. The project directory contains 
the bin, src, and lib directories.

The Linux `tree` command list us our project directory in a tree-like format.

```
$ tree
.
├── bin
│   └── zetcode
│       └── Version.class
├── lib
│   └── mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar
└── src
    └── zetcode
        └── Version.java
```

Binaries go into the bin directory, libraries into the lib, and sources into the src directory. Note that directories must match the package names.

To compile the sources, we use the following command:

`$ javac -d bin src/zetcode/Version.java`

With the `-d` option, we set the directory for the created class files.

The following command executes the program:

```
$ java -cp bin:lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin.jar zetcode.Version 
5.5.37-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
```