# Can't run Java class with MySQL connector from Termainal

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, macos

Nobody has been able to suggest a working solution so I'm trying this again as a new post.

Simply, I cannot run my java class Version.class, which uses a mysql connector .jar file from the command line.  It works fine in Eclipse, just not from Terminal.  Here is my file structure:

I can successfully execute from Eclipse IDE, but when trying to execute a java .class file from Terminal I'm having some issues.

`~/dropbox/workspace/mysqltut/src/zetcode/Version.java`
`~/dropbox/workspace/mysqltut/src/zetcode/Version.class`
`~/dropbox/workspace/mysqltut/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar`

After navigating to `~/dropbox/workspace/mysqltut/src/` in Terminal, I run the following:

`java -cp .:lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar zetcode/Version`

```
May 03, 2014 10:54:31 PM zetcode.Version main
SEVERE: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at zetcode.Version.main(Version.java:24)
```

Is something wrong with my syntax/file structure or is something not installed properly?

Comment: Please, show the code. A compilable/runnable example is preferred. (@prabugp yep, wasn't aware that I have enough rep to comment)

Comment: :) happens. I posted after seeing that you do have enough reps.

Comment: I have provided an answer for the exact same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/24440716/2008247

Answer (score 1):

You're running this from the src folder. and the lib is a sibling of src and not a child. So, when you're setting the classpath to lib, I believe it's looking for a lib inside the src folder. Can you tweak your classpath to .:../lib/... or come one level up to mysqsltut and run the program?

Comment: Great! This worked. Thanks so much I've been going crazy.  Though this worked, is there a conventional file structure you can recommend?  Should the lib folder me somewhere else?  Also can you explain the various switches for moving through file structure in terminal?  I'm assuming ".:" is the same as "../" correct?  What is ".;" and some of the more commonly used switches?  Thanks again!

Comment: Also, how would I run this if I moved up to mysqltut?  using src/zetcode/Version doesnt work as it returns `Error:  Could not find or load main class src.zetcode.Version`

Comment: Ah.. questions, questions, questions. super, you're doing the right thing. You'd probably get started here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html which explains what classpath is and how you can set it in various ways. To answer your question, . is the current directory, : is the path separator for linux, i believe. ../ is one level up. As for your second comment, try `src/zetcode.Version` and let me know if that works. Also, if your original question is answered, please mark it so.

Comment: Thanks prabu.  I did markup as soon as your suggestion worked about an hour ago.  is it not showing?

Comment: And from mysqltut, using `java -cp lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar src/zetcode.Version` as you suggested does not work. It only returns `Error:  Could not find or load main class src.zetcode.Version`  I believe when executing a class file you must be in the package folder hence why only zetcode.Version is recognized when I'm in src.

Comment: I still don't understand why `.:../lib/...` worked.  If I'm in src, shouldn't `../lib/...` work?

Comment: You gave an upvote and marking a question as answered is a bit different. and your current directory is searched by default, but that only applies when you don't explicitly give the -cp option. If you're setting it manually at the command line, you must include '.' also.

Comment: sorry prab. i thought upvoting as the OP was the same as the OP saying this answered their question.  I will mark as answered.